# React Native Apps in android get closed with react-native-contacts everytime

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to use react-native-contacts and create methods which is getting used in useEffect. This is working fine for ios and apps get shutdown everytime in android devices.

```
export const loadContacts = (callback?: any) => {
  getAll().then(contacts => {
    callback(contacts);
  });
};

export const requestContactsPermission = (callback?: any) => {
  if (isAndroid) {
    PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CONTACTS, {
      title: 'Contacts',
      message: 'This app would like to view your contacts.',
      buttonPositive: 'Please accept',
    }).then(res => {
      loadContacts(callback);
    });
  } else {
    loadContacts(callback);
  }
};

export const checkContactsPermission = async () => {
  if (isAndroid) {
    const isPermissionGranted = await PermissionsAndroid.check(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CONTACTS,
    );
    console.log('permi granted android', isPermissionGranted);
    return isPermissionGranted;
  } else {
    const isPermissionGranted = await checkPermission();
    console.log('permi granted ios', isPermissionGranted);
    return !!(isPermissionGranted === 'authorized');
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you please provide the error you're getting, or try to log each of the functions to know exactly where the error is happening

Comment: isPermissionGranted is coming false in console and app get close automatically

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are setting isContactPermissionGranted to true regardless of the result in your useEffect, i suggest that you console.log the "res" value and follow up that function with `.catch((error)=>console.log(error))` and also i think that you should replace `return isPermissionGranted` with `return (isPermissionGranted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS)` in your android function

Comment: Getting only three options authorized | denied | undefined no 'granted' is there or it will return false everytime

Comment: can you try ignoring the type error and using 'granted' regardless, it depends on the sdk version you are on so i'd give it a try just to make sure

Comment: you might also wanna add ```<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />``` in your manifest file

Comment: same error app is getting closed.     useEffect(() => {
        checkContactsPermission().then((res) => {
            dispatch(setPaymentState({
                isContactPermissionGranted: true
            }))
            setLoading(false);
        });
    }, [isContactPermissionGranted]);

Comment: this is my useEffect method where i am calling permission

Comment: it seems like you are setting isContactPermissionGranted to true regardless of the result, i suggest that you console.log the "res" value and follow up that function with ```.catch((error)=>console.log(error))``` and also i think that you should replace ```return isPermissionGranted``` with ```return (isPermissionGranted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS)``` in your android function

Comment: it's still giving false value